# What is the difference between System.Transaction and System.Data.Common.DbTransaction?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4, transactions, linq-to-entities, transactionscope

I use Linq-to-Entity (EF 4.0) in my project. I want to use transactions in My Code. i found two way to use transactions in my code. What is the difference between System.Transaction and System.Data.Common.DbTransaction? and which is performance better?

first:

```
            using (testEntities ent = new testEntities())
        {
            ent.Connection.Open();
            using (System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction = ent.Connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    ...

                    int er1 = ent.SaveChanges();
                    if (er1 > 0)
                        success = true;
                    else
                        success = false;

                    ...

                    int er2 = ent.SaveChanges();
                    if (er2 > 0)
                        success = true;
                    else
                        success = false;
                }
                catch
                {
                    success = false;
                }

                success = false;

                if (success)
                    transaction.Commit();
                else
                    transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

second:

```
            using (testEntities ent = new testEntities())
        {
            ent.Connection.Open();
            using (TransactionScope tscope= new TransactionScope())
            {

                ...

                int er1 = ent.SaveChanges();

                ...

                int er2 = ent.SaveChanges();


                tscope.Complete();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From msdn

> The System.Transactions namespace contains classes that allow you to write your own transactional application and resource manager. Specifically, you can create and participate in a transaction (local or distributed) with one or multiple participants.

DbTransactions are for database transactions only. 
TransactionScope gives you automatic transaction enrollment ability. It will enroll or create a new transactions for you. This can inlude database or distributed transactions.

Check the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) for more information.